# Cual es la complejidad del algoritmo criba de Eratóstenes con BitSet?

Tags: java, complejidad

estoy implementando `BitSet` en la criba de Eratóstenes, ya que con arreglos y listas enlazadas se me hace demasiado ineficiente con respecto a uso de memoria.
El problema, es que, aunque la criba de Eratóstenes tiene una complejidad de `O(N*log(log(N)))`, con la modificación que le hice se disminuye el tiempo de ejecución bastante.
El código es el siguiente:

```
private long encontrarPrimos(long n) {
    System.out.println(n);
    long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();


    LongBitSet bs = new LongBitSet(n + 1);
    bs.clear(0);
    bs.clear(1);

    for (long i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (bs.get(i)) {
            for (long j = i; i * j <= n; j++) {
                bs.clear(i * j);
            }
        }
    }

    long fin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long finalTime = fin - inicio;
    System.out.println(bs.cardinality());
    return finalTime;
}
```

Y esta es la case que se encarga de convertir el long dado como parámetro a un `Bitset array`.

```
public class LongBitSet {
    /**
     * Valor maximo que se guarda en un BitSet
     */
    private static final long BITSET_SIZE = 274877906944L;
    private BigInteger bitSetSize;
    BitSet[] bitsets;

    public LongBitSet(long limit) {
        bitsets = new BitSet[(int) (limit / BITSET_SIZE + 1)];
        // set all bits by default
        for (int i = 0; i < bitsets.length; i++) {
            bitsets[i] = new BitSet();
            int max = (int) (i == bitsets.length - 1
                    ? limit % BITSET_SIZE : BITSET_SIZE);
            max = (max < 0) ? -1*max : max; 
            bitsets[i].set(0, max);
            //System.out.println(max);
            //System.out.println(bitsets[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Limpia un bit especificado
     * @param pos 
     */
    public void clear(long pos) {
        bitsets[(int) (pos / BITSET_SIZE)].clear((int) (pos % BITSET_SIZE));
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene el valor del bit especificado
     * @param pos
     * @return 
     */
    public boolean get(long pos) {
        return bitsets[(int) (pos / BITSET_SIZE)].get((int) (pos % BITSET_SIZE));
    }
    /**
     * Ubtener el numero de bytes ingresados
     * @return 
     */
    public long cardinality() {
        long cardinality = 0;
        for (BitSet bs : bitsets) {
            cardinality += bs.cardinality();
            //System.out.println(bs);
        }
        return cardinality;
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es si la modificación que le hice, matemáticamente afecta a su complejidad, y, si es así, que es lo que cambia y por qué cambia?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías aclarar cuál es la ***modificación*** que le hiciste? Y sobre todo, ¿a qué le hiciste la modificación, a la clase LongBitSet o al método de Eratóstenes? En tu algoritmo no veo nada que indique que haya una ganancia u optimización en la complejidad del método. Me atrevería a decir que sólo has mejorado el uso de memoria (como era de esperar) y por lo tanto, aumenta la eficiencia en *lectura-escritura* en un ¿7.x? (alguien que me corrija). Saludos

Comment: Solo un pequeño detalle, tu código esta midiendo el tiempo de i/o el cual es un poco impredecible. Si para medir el tiempo de ejecucion has usado lo que has puesto deberias quitar las dos lineas de System.out.println y hacerlo otra vez.

Comment: La modificación que hice fue agregar BitSet al método de Eratóstenes, ya que primero, fue para optimización de memoria, además de agregar la constante BITSET_SIZE, la cual disminuye el tiempo de ejecucion y terminacion del algoritmo. Aunque no se si esto, como dices @MauricioContreras, seea posiblemente porque no se utiliza tanta memoria, y el procesador no tiene que pedir datos a cada nada de la memoria, esa podría ser mi teoria.

Comment: @Labosis estoy midiendo el tiempo de ejecución, además para sacar la complejidad. Si te refieres a la impresión del número y la cantidad de primos, tienes razon, no habia caido en cuenta de esto. Ya está corregido.

Comment: Es precisamente lo que te comenté. Solo has optimizado el uso de recursos, pero la complejidad del algoritmo sigue siendo la misma.

Comment: Ok entiendo, entonces sigue siendo `O(N*log(log(N)))` a pesar del cambio hecho?
Me he dado de cuenta que en cierto punto, un algoritmo con complejidad lineal puede ser más eficiente, especialmente en este caso, ya que calcula la cantidad de números primos por debajo de N. Cómo podría mejorar la complejidad lineal?? Dudo que se pueda con una función menos asintótica, como por ejemplo N*log(n)

Comment: Si, exactamente, sigue siendo la misma complejidad. Imagina una carretera de 2 canales por la que circulas con tu vehículo con motor que desarrolla hasta X despalzamiento. De tanto en tanto debes adelantar a algún conductor y eso te retrasa. La mejora que tu has realizado es simplemente convertir la carretera de 2 canales en una autopista de 4 canales de ida y 4 de vuelta. El motor sin embargo es el mismo. Por otro lado, siempre una complejidad lineal es más eficiente que una logarítmica, pero has escogido un algoritmo que en la actualidad se considera ineficiente.

Comment: Ok bro te entiendo completamente. Por otro lado, no hay otros algoritmos que sean mucho más rápidos que la criba de Eratóstenes?

Comment: Deberia ser mas rapido el simple for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++){
         if(n%i==0){
             a++;
            }
         }
Menos asignaciones de memoria, punteros y demas es mas eficiente en ese sentido, hace la prueba y fijate lo simple en programacion a veces es lo mas eficiente

Comment: @LucianoMontañez si funciona, pero para numeros con pocas cifras, el algoritmo que utilizo es para numeros de 10 a 15 cifras.

Comment: le hechaste un ojo a esto ? https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_de_primalidad_AKS

Comment: @LucianoMontañez ok bro, gracias.